# Ecranning quotes in Windows CMD

Tags: cmd

Can I do something like ecranning quotes in variable? For example,

```
if "%1"=="/?" goto :help
```

Will return error if argument is "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"%~1"`. The tilde modifier will strip quotes from `%1`, if present.

Unfortunately there is no general safe way to process strings with special chars (quotes, parentheses, caret) in batch files. There are always some cases that blow up whatever you write.

Comment: if "%1"=="/?" goto :help
will go to help if %1 is " 
But it shouldn't.

Comment: @user23791 Why do you think it shouldn't? We don't have precise specs on its behavior (and indeed on the quotation marks parsing by `cmd`), so maybe that's what was intended by the developers. :)  CMD language is a huge collection of kludges anyway. If you need precise handling of strings, use e.g. WSH which is bundled with every realistic version of Windows out there. That said, I always use the tilde expansion in batch files and never had a problem with it "in the wild".